# how to validate email properly while register and edit users in django

Tags: django, registration

I am not using django default admin dashboard and i am using my own custom template for the admin.but here i got some problem while editing and updating the user.I want to make email of every user unique in the database this code in my forms.py does pretty well while adding the user but while updating it i got some problem regarding the email.Since I have done the email unique in forms.py it is giving me error while updating also.How can i update users so that the edited user can have the same email but not same as the other user's email address.

> forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Email Already Exists')
        return email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', "email", "password1", "password2",'is_superuser','is_staff','is_active']
```

> views.py

```
def register(request):

if not request.user.is_superuser:
    messages.warning(request, 'Permission Denied.You have no permission to register users.')
    return redirect('students:home')
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        messages.success(request,'user created with username {}'.format(user.username))
        return redirect('students:our_users')
else:
    form =RegisterForm()
return render(request,'students/register.html',{'form':form})

def editusers(request,id):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        messages.warning(request, 'Permission Denied.You have no permission to perform this action.')
        return redirect('students:our_users')
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'students/edit_users.html',{'user':user})


def updateusers(request,id):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        messages.warning(request, 'Permission Denied.You have no permission to perform this action.')
        return redirect('students:our_users')
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST,instance=user)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=True)
        user.save()
        messages.success(request,'{} updated'.format(user.username))
        return redirect('students:our_users')
    else:
        messages.error(request,'Error in Form')
        return redirect('students:edit_user',user.id)
```

> register template

```
    <form action="" method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                        {% bootstrap_form form %}
                        <div class="text-xs-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

> edituser template

```
<form action="{% url 'students:update_user' user.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

<div class="form-group"><label for="id_username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" autofocus class="form-control" value="{{user.username}}" placeholder="Username" title="Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only." required id="id_username">


    <small class="form-text text-muted">Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</small>

</div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="id_email">Email</label><input type="email" name="email" value="{{user.email}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" title="" required id="id_email"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="id_password1">Password</label><input type="password" name="password1" value="{{user.password}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" title="Your password must contain at least 8 characters.Your password can&amp;#39;t be entirely numeric." required id="id_password1">


    <small class="form-text text-muted"><ul><li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li><li>Your password can&#39;t be entirely numeric.</li></ul></small>

</div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="id_password2">Password confirmation</label><input type="password" name="password2" value="{{user.password}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password confirmation" title="Enter the same password as before, for verification." required id="id_password2">


    <small class="form-text text-muted">Enter the same password as before, for verification.</small>

</div>
<div class="form-group"><div class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" name="is_superuser" {% if user.is_superuser %}checked="checked" {% endif %}
                                                       class="form-check-input" id="id_is_superuser"><label class="form-check-label" for="id_is_superuser" title="Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.">Admin status</label>


    <small class="form-text text-muted">Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.</small>

</div></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><div class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" name="is_staff" {% if user.is_staff %}checked="checked" {% endif %} class="form-check-input" id="id_is_staff"><label class="form-check-label" for="id_is_staff" title="Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.">Staff status</label>


    <small class="form-text text-muted">Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.</small>

</div></div>
<div class="form-group"><div class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" {% if user.is_active %}checked="checked" {% endif %} name="is_active"  class="form-check-input" id="id_is_active"><label class="form-check-label" for="id_is_active" title="Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.">Active</label>


    <small class="form-text text-muted">Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.</small>

</div></div>


                    <div class="text-xs-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
         return email
    else User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise ValidationError('Email Already Exists')
    return email
```

Here I am checking if form has any instance and if that instance has any primary key. This instance attribute is set in form when you pass it from view, for example in your code: `form = RegisterForm(request.POST,instance=user)`.